# javascript code into email tracking method (php)

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'm stuck trying to integrate some javascript code in my php script.

Here my case :
I'm trying to integrate a 1x1 email tracking pixel into an HTML email/page. 
I have 2 files :

1. **htacess** : make a redirection png -> track.php
2. **track.php** : I display the invisible 1x1 blank image here.

I call the image like that : domain.com/myimage.png, so it redirects and execute the code included in track.php to display the blank image.

It's working. But now, I want to execute some javascript lines in track.php like
track.php :

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  <JAVASCRIPT CODE>
  <DISPLAY THE IMAGE>
  die();
?>
```

When I call the image, the image is displayed, but the javascript code is not executed. I tried to add the javascript before or after the echo image, but same things, the JS code is not executed

For information, the javascript code track the pixel in an other website and display a blank image too.

Any help ? is-it even possible to make that ?

Thank you by advance for any help or tips!

Comment: No, that is of course not possible. Images can not contain “embedded” JavaScript in a web context.

Comment: Not possible. Also, that's not how you output an image from a PHP script. You need to echo the file contents, not the file name. Also, you try to output a GIF and settings a PNG content type.

Comment: thank you for your fast answers @CBroe

Comment: thank you for your fast answer @AlinPurcaru (yes, i made a mistake while writting the question here about how to display the image)

Comment: But there is any trick to make that ?

Comment: If you want to execute JavaScript, you have to embed it into the document _as_ JavaScript. And for email you best forget about that right away, because most email clients do not execute JavaScript at all (for good reasons.)

Comment: @Soupio Are you trying the Javascript to run on the email itself?

Comment: @Ivar : yes, i'm sure the javascript code is working. Just with my test, it's not executed

Comment: @CBroe : and let's say i forgot the javascript part, can i display 2 images (one after the other one). So i make 2 echo file_get_contents

Comment: No, you can not send two images in response to one single request either.

Comment: Can't you add both "images" to  your e-mail to execute both PHP tracking codes you need?

Comment: Well, i can add both "image", but i wanted to make 2in1. But if it's not possible, i'll use this option :(